# datepickerfield sencha touch 2 - how to change default placeHolder color from black to grey?

Tags: css, html, datepicker, sencha-touch-2, placeholder

There is:

```
{
    xtype: 'datepickerfield',
    placeHolder : 'Date',
}
```

As resul, HTML file displays:

```
<input class="x-input-el x-form-field x-input-text" type="text" id="ext-element-121" name="date" placeholder="Date" style="color: red!important;">
```

Unfortunately, the word "Date" displayed in black and nothing helps. Tried css, styles for placeHolder html5, read Sencha Docs. Nothing helps, solution was not found yet.

Is that impossible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `-webkit-text-fill-color`.

The easiest way to target a specific field is like this:

```
{
    xtype: 'datepickerfield',
    placeHolder : 'Date',
    cls: 'your-class'
}

.your-class .x-form-field {
    -webkit-text-fill-color: red;
}
```

---

**EDIT**

To complete the answer, you probably want the text to return back to the default color after a user has made a date selection, so; on the date picker change event add `removeCls`

*Example*

```
onDatePickerChange: function(this, date, options ) {
    this.removeCls('your-class');
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your extended answer! It works. You've made my day.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: red !important;
}
```

Comment: Yes. And it doesn't help. It affects all placeholders but datepickerfield's one.